# Return a Char array in C

Tags: c

I am building a cipher program but i can't figure out how to return an array of char[]
my cipher method

```
char *cipherinput(int ciphercount){
int i=0;
char *cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];


if(ciphercount>=2){
    printf("Enter the Cipher!\n");
    //loop through and add
    for(i=0;i<ciphercount;i++){
        scanf(" %c", cipher[i]);
    }
}

   return cipher;
}
```

my main method has

```
#define MAX_CIPHER_SIZE 16
#define MAX_TEXT_SIZE 256
int main()
{
   int ciphercount=0, textcount=0,i=0,j=0,k=0;
   int *cipher_, *text_, N=0,N_;

   printf("Enter size of Cipher!\n");
   scanf("%d", &ciphercount);

   if(ciphercount>=2){
    cipher_ = cipherinput(ciphercount);
   }
   else{
     printf("Start again / Cipher size should be greater or equal to 2\n");
     main();
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

I've tried several methods such as char** (string) with no success.

Comment: first off - this `char *cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];` makes an array of strings. I dont think this is what you want

Comment: you can't return arrays in `c`. If you really want to, you'll have to wrap it in a `struct`

Comment: If you return an array you need to indicate how long it is, or have some kind of convention like a `NULL` pointer as the last element in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to stack memory, which is undefined behavior. Most likely your returned string will be corrupted shortly after the function returns or after the invocation of another function.

This is closer to what you want:

```
char* cipherinput(int ciphercount) {
    int i=0;
    char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE+1]; // +1 to guarantee null termination.
    cipher[0] = '\0';

    if(ciphercount>=2){
        printf("Enter the Cipher!\n");
        //loop through and add
        for(i=0;i<ciphercount;i++){
            scanf(" %c", cipher[i]);
        }
        cipher[ciphercount] = '\0'; // null terminate
    }

    return strdup(cipher);   // this is the same as ptr=malloc(strlen(cipher+1)) followed by strcpy(ptr,cipher)
}
```

The function returns a copy of the string the user typed in.  The caller of this function is expected to invoke `free` on the returned pointer after it's done with it.  If `ciphercount < 2`, the function will return an empty string.

Comment: why is it returning an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Normal way 1, Allocate result in function and return it

```
    char *cipherinput(int ciphercount){
      char *cipher = malloc(MAX_CIPHER_SIZE);
...
      return cipher;
    }
```

Note that your caller will have to `free` the result

Normal way 2, Caller creates and passes result buffer

```
void cipherinput(int ciphercount, char * cipher){
 ....
}
```

caller goes

```
    char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
    cipherinput(x, cipher);
```

Normal way #3. HAve fixed static buffer in function. NOTE THIS IS NOT rentrant or thread safe.

```
char *cipherinput(int ciphercount){
  static char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
  .....
  return cipher;
}
```

In general #2 is probably best since you are less likely to leak

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `char *cipher` outside your function

```
char *cipherinput(int ciphercount){
     int i=0;
     char *cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
     //...
     return *cipher;
}
```

You need to allocate memory for your cipher buffer. Your `cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE]` will not exist once the `cipherinput`  function returns. This is the most common approach:

```
 char* cipherinput(int ciphercount) {
        // ...
        char *cipher = malloc( sizeof(char) * (MAX_CIPHER_SIZE+1) ); // +1 to guarantee null termination.

        //...
        return cipher;
    }
```

This approach requires you to remember to free the memory allocated for `cipher` once you do not needed.

In embedded systems you may want to avoid memory allocation, since allocation and deallocation may not be timely operation. 
In such case, the best approach is to pass a buffer to your function:

```
char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE+1];    // buffer outside the function
cipherinput(ciphercount, cipher);  // function call
```

Function implementation:

```
void cipherinput(int ciphercount, char * cipher){
 // access elements of cipher buffer via cipher[i]);
 // ...
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always one by definition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Thank you. Good comment! I like to use `sizeof(char)` since it underlines the type of variables which I want to keep in the memory.